# How can I draw this block diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw [this diagram](https://www.draw.io/?lightbox=1&highlight=0000ff&edit=_blank&layers=1&nav=1#R7Vltb9o6FP41kbYrdUrsOIGPEFiHxKCUVvfufsslLkQKMUtCgf36a8d27CQgKJQtlZBQa58Xx37OeY5jx4Decnuf%2BKvFdxLgyABmsDVgzwDAsgEw2M8MdlziWpAL5kkYCCMlmIa%2FsBCaQroOA5yWDDNCoixclYUzEsd4lpVkfpKQTdnshUTlp678Oa4JpjM%2Fqkv%2FDoNsIaSW01aKbzicL8SjW8DliqUvjcVK0oUfkI0mgn0DegkhGW8ttx6OGHgSF%2B739YC2mFiC4%2BwUh11r1w26o1%2BT7fxhlU3uH1DHu7NsPsyrH63Fir3x6KnTGz9SaWdqeNBo9Ube43g0FsvIdhKbhKzjALPhTQN2N4sww9OVP2PaDc0GKltky4j2LNp8IXE2Fb5Fn4cbMPf6csQKX3GS4a0mEsu7x2SJs2RHTYQWQLEakWvQdHh%2Fo0XOEeFYaEGzZLb5IlvmxdgKUNoQmL4FX6eO7%2BDRex48UTjNp8fnkcexbji0tt08aN0atMN%2BL6USlcFORKfRTVd%2BXILX%2BblmrOvOSEQSA3aoMpn%2F53%2BiU6U%2FOh1zb%2BuzIeA0GcJ3L%2F4yjHbcfUlikuYBKpmkeRSYgbnallUbARJT2vwpuTKP9R0fK1fGJI94MWnamvP%2FqFp3EYWPSfOiUvQknCgHlEp6rM1WhRiAiEbhmK1V2Mo0OmsYoIbhUSs0KmQoLzsA0cIDkCo9VPxdStuw9zzkMqgNyeNbDCkpxARskiUaMSGHFQkqMYmVdxWdKjIWTCYCfDhtMZxHp8BVqAqkFNkQo5uybClozZ2SQ9T6gpSGE1B5OZqXIKJSWpqSErJQzLU5VGOZd4uA6sJymgm7Wj5yDlKKcxrK5G14wXPdcsGz3PZpBc%2FOo3OditeqVbxuZzj4t3MrdLdCdyt0t0L3HoXORqYsYEdLnXutQteuFbrx1BsM6Z%2Fxw6D5B5Eqpqj95zcPeQzdfxKZPNMENvsjb9Af9VhzyCqy3F0aDnf1cGK33VNT%2BHrHk2IZGt7Dfqd%2B1MNx0GEXFbQ3i%2Fw0DWd7ANQAw9sw%2B4dhT9fIez9EJFi7t9U7O9mJ6ZI0J9b9oeuUW96TfgeDk5J1MsMnHHwzP5nj7IQbCByULmLqwdZCifZEUsoSHPlZ%2BFq%2BvtkXXfGEBxKybevQHYJru1VK8rULP%2F3CpTpUqzyU064NxdGpDUXzwd9pZitmkB6eNALlJ9FpiycdmpttvdUDHvOgDT5vxZkiehfQCNRoNLEn4B1Z5Oo0ss6ikXU9Gtmn0si50ehSGkFU2UecozSCb%2FWoUrXmcSUawTqN4MScgL%2ButB%2BdSqTSbqRY9eeIJN%2BTGkIkq115lbyASIdfk96bSJW9AiHwW5K8%2FjHj8uw%2BM1MlKyyNE4oh%2B1lxfnbLpD2%2BTbQbld0fcptwqpSsZvdRDwf8Hj6g5vDhYG4fT9lWo1K2Hv0PmLK2uKC4bvrVv32%2B48sGOOf027i3DfkRsyHJ%2FSHrMajctgHzwupqiBtfzVzd9cL%2B%2Fw%3D%3D) into latex, I have tried using the svg package, but the image is broken:

[image]

I have also tried converting it using online converters to eps format but the result is the same. 
Finally I have also tried exporting svg format to tikz but I cannot manage to convert it. I don't know how to use Inkscape tho.

Do you believe is there any other way to make convert this diagram to any latex format of drawing?

Comment: Why you not include this picture as it is with `\includegraphics[width=...]{<file name>}`? Or simple redraw it with use of `tikz` or `pstricks` or ... packets?. Image is not so complicated ...

Comment: That is not too hard, but as we are not a "do this for me service", I'd suggest you have a look at some of the examples in this gallery http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/ and then ask again when you have a more concrete question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very similar to the @Schrödinger's cat answer. Tiny differences are in definitions of nodes' styles and drawing of connection between nodes:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 12mm and 6mm,
   box/.style = {draw, text width=8em, align=flush center,
                 font=\sffamily\bfseries},
   lbl/.style = {fill=white, inner sep=1pt, 
                 font=\sffamily\small},
            > = Stealth  
                        ]
\node (n1) [box] {CONTADOR ASINCRONO};
\node (n2) [box, right=of n1]   {CIRCUITO TRUNCADOR};
\node (n3) [box, below=of n2]   {Circuito QUE ENCIENDE LA BALIZA};
%
\node (n4) [box, right= 12mm of n3.south east] {OSCILOSCOPIO};
\node (n5) [box, right= 12mm of n3.north east] {BALIZA};
\node (n6) [box, above=of n2-| n4] {LEDs CONTADOR};
%
    \begin{scope}[every path/.style = {rounded corners,->}]
\draw   ([xshift=-2em] n1.north) |- (n6);
\draw   (n2.north) -- ++ (0,7mm) -| node[pos=0.25,lbl] {CLEAR} (n1);
\draw   ([xshift=2em] n1.south) -- ++ (0,-7mm) -| node[pos=0.25,lbl] {Q4Q2} (n2);
\draw   (n1) |- node[pos=0.5,lbl] {Q3Q0Q2*} (n3);
%
\draw   (n3.east) -- ++ (6mm,0) |- (n5);
\draw   (n3.east) -- ++ (6mm,0) |- (n4);
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This diagram costs a few minutes to code so if the attempts of converting it fail, you may just draw it. That way you inherit the font size etc. from the document in which you embed it.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
 \begin{scope}[box/.style={minimum height=#1,minimum width=10em,
    draw,align=center,node font=\bfseries},box/.default=5em]
  \node[box] (A) {CONTADOR\\ ASINCRONO};
  \node[box,right=2em of A] (B) {CIRCUITO\\ TUNCATOR};
  \node[box,below=4em of B] (C) {CIRCUITO QUE\\ \dots \\ \dots};
  \node[box=2em,right=5em of C.north east,anchor=south west] (D) {BALIZA};
  \node[box=2em,right=5em of C.south east,anchor=north west] (E) {BALIZA};
  \node[box=2em,above=10em of D.north west,anchor=south west] (F) {BALIZA};
 \end{scope}
 \begin{scope}[rounded corners=1ex,-stealth,nodes={fill=white},thick]
  \draw (B.north) -- ++ (0,2em) -| node[pos=0.25]{CLEAR}(A);
  \draw (A.-50) -- ++ (0,-2em) -| node[pos=0.25]{Q4Q2}(B);
  \draw (A) |- node{Q3Q0Q2\textsuperscript{*}} (C);
  \path (C.east) -- coordinate (aux) (D.west);
  \draw (C.east) -- (C-|aux) |- (D);
  \draw (C.east) -- (C-|aux) |- (E);
  \draw (A.120) |- (F);
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, I did not have the passion to punch in the texts, which would be the most time consuming task. Note also that copying this code and using `quotes` does not make the code more elegant nor concise.